# Failed to run composer require symfony/mailer

Tags: composer-php, symfony4

I'm trying to run composer require symfony/mailer to use it in Symfony 4 project, but it returns an error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/mailer[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.8] require symfony/mime ^5.2.6|^6.0 -> found symfony/mime[v5.2.6, ..., v5.4.9, v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.1] but the package is fixed to v4.4.42 (lock file
version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/mailer ^5.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/mailer[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.8].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

And when I run composer -vvv --no-plugins require --no-scripts -W symfony/mailer I got this :

```
  Problem 1
- symfony/mailer[v5.4.0, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.5, v5.4.7, v5.4.8] require 
  symfony/mime ^5.2.6|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/mime[v5.2.6, 
  v5.2.7, v5.2.9, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.3.0, v5.3.2, v5.3.4, 
  v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.11
  , v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.4.0, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9, 
  v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.7, v6.0.8, v6.0.9, v6.1.0, 
  v6.1.1].
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.7.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.8.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.2.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.4.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.0.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.12.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.11.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.10.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.9.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.7.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.8.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.2.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.3.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.4.0.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.7.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.9.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.2.6.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.11.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.13.
- __root__ dev-develop conflicts with symfony/mime v5.3.14.
- symfony/mime[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.7, v6.0.8, v6.0.9] require php >=8.0.2 -> your php version (7.3.21) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/mime[v6.1.0, v6.1.1] require php >=8.1 -> your php version (7.3.21) does not satisfy that requirement.
- __root__ is present at version dev-develop and cannot be modified by Composer
- Root composer.json requires symfony/mailer ^5.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/mailer[v5.4.0, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.5, v5.4.7, v5.4.8].
```

Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: From your question: `Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.` ==>> `composer require -W symfony/mailer`.

Answer (score 0):

`symfony/mailer` is fixed/locked to `v4.4.42` in your project.

Run the Composer require command with `--with-all-dependencies` (`-W`) to see if it solves your problem:

```bash
composer require -W symfony/mailer
```

`symfony/mailer` is the only problem you have with your (current) lock file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it too but it didn't work :( same error

Comment: Please check if `composer -vvv --no-plugins require --no-scripts -W symfony/mailer` gives a different result. I also wondered a bit because normally Composer mentions the lock file explicitly.

Comment: I couldn't add it as comment so I edit my post to show result of your command